# Query to skip first row after id changes in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a long table like the following. The table adds two similar rows after the id changes. E.g in the following table when ID changes from 1 to 2 a duplicate record is added. All I need is a SELECT query to skip this and all other duplicate records only if the ID changes.

```
# | name| id
--+-----+---
1 | abc | 1 
2 | abc | 1 
3 | abc | 1 
4 | abc | 1 
5 | abc | 1 
5 | abc | 2 
6 | abc | 2 
7 | abc | 2 
8 | abc | 2 
9 | abc | 2
```

and so on

Comment: Please edit your question with the output you want.  And, do the rows have a unique id?

Comment: @thanks marc_s, yes the rows have unique id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I achieved it by using the following query in SQL server.

```
select #, name, id
from table
group by #, name, id
having count(*) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following `CTEs` to simulate `LAG` window function not available in SQL Server 2008:

```
;WITH CTE_RN AS (
   SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [#], id) AS rn
   FROM #mytable
), CTE_LAG AS (
   SELECT t1.[#], t1.name, 
          t1.id AS curId, t2.id AS prevId,
          t1.[#] AS cur#, t2.[#] AS lag#
   FROM CTE_RN t1
   LEFT JOIN CTE_RN t2 ON t1.rn = t2.rn + 1 )
```

You can now filter out the 'duplicate' records using the above `CTE_LAG` and the following predicate in your `WHERE` clause:

```
;WITH ( 
   ... cte definitions here
) SELECT *
FROM CTE_LAG
WHERE (NOT ((prevId <> curId) AND (cur# = lag#))) OR (prevId IS NULL)
```

If `prevId <> curId` **and** `cur# = lag#`, then there is a change in the value of the `id` column **and** the following record has the same `[#]` value as the previous one, i.e. it is a duplicate.

Hence, using `NOT` on `(prevId <> curId) AND (cur# = lag#)`, filters out all 'duplicate' records. This means record `(5, abc, 2)` will be eliminated.

[SQL Fiddle Demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/072b7/5)

P.S. You can also add column `name` in the logical expression of the `WHERE` clause, depending on what defines a 'duplicate'.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `NOT EXISTS` to eliminate the duplicates:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    yourtable AS T
WHERE   NOT EXISTS 
        (   SELECT  1 
            FROM    yourtable AS T2 
            WHERE   T.[#] = T2.[#] 
            AND     T2.ID > T.ID
        );
```

This will return:

```
#   name    ID
------------------
.   ...     .
4   abc     1
5   abc     2
6   abc     2
.   ...     .
```

*... (Some irrelevant rows have been removed from the start and the end)*

If you wanted the first record to be retained, rather than the last, then just change the condition `T2.ID > T.ID` to `T2.ID < T.ID`.